# Prevent <audio> controls' automatic scaling in iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, css, mobile-safari

Safari/iOS automatically resizes `<audio>`'s controls to always have them in the same physical size. All would be well if they didn't end up covering important parts of the page.

Is there a way to either **prevent this behavior**, to **resize the `<audio>`** to its rendered height or, at least, to **know its rendered height**? I'd rather not use a custom player.

This is how it's rendered on [this page](http://alexcj.it/traccia/i-like-this-sound-ft-alia/), zoomed out and zoomed in:

---

[image: Zoomed out]

---

[image: Zoomed in]

---